# while statment is stuck on an infinite loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

```
task = ""
while task != "e" or task != "d": 
    task = raw_input("would you like to encrypt or decrypt\r\n:- ").lower()
keyword = raw_input("enter a keyword:-").lower()
keyphrase = raw_input("enter a key phrase:-").lower()
```

does anyone know why when the code runs, the while statment is looped over and over even when a correct input has been entered. i think it is something to do with the parameters in the while statment but im not sure.

I have tried the while statment with just one condition and this works, however don't see why its not working with multiple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `or` statement always evaluates to `True`.

If `task == 'e'`, then `task != 'd'`, and so the `while` loop evaluates to `True`, thus making the loop continue indefinitely.

Change it to something like:

```
task = " "
while task not in "ed":
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

for any task, task != "e" or task != "d" wont be false